# Get data from two tables using LINQ without any column key

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two list in c#. Both list are of different types (different object).
I want to get data from both these lists into new third list using LINQ. 
This third list has all the required properties which can store data from both the lists.
Here are my two source lists

```
var posts = new List<GeneralPost>()
            {
                new GeneralPost(){PostID=1, PostDescription = "Post 1" , PostTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
                new GeneralPost(){PostID=2, PostDescription = "Post 2" , PostTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)},
                new GeneralPost(){PostID=3, PostDescription = "Post 3" , PostTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)},
                new GeneralPost(){PostID=4, PostDescription = "Post 4" , PostTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)},

        };

var products = new List<EnquiryProduct>()
            {
                new EnquiryProduct(){BusinessId=1, ProductDescription="ProductDesc 1", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) },
                new EnquiryProduct(){BusinessId=2, ProductDescription="ProductDesc 2", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0) },
                new EnquiryProduct(){BusinessId=3, ProductDescription="ProductDesc 3", CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
            };
```

I have tried this -

```
 var total = (from p in posts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         from pro in products.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             PostId = p.PostID,
                             ProductId = pro.BusinessId,
                             PostDes = p.PostDescription,
                             ProductDes = pro.ProductDescription
                         }).ToList();
```

Here is my output expectation-

```
PostId  ProductId   PostDescrition  ProductDescriptin
1       null        Post 1      null
2       null        Post 2      null
3       null        Post 3      null
4       null        Post 4      null
null    1           null        ProductDesc 1
null    2           null        ProductDesc 2
null    3           null        ProductDesc 3
```

Comment: `Concat` will do the job

Comment: What you have tried is cartesian product, while the expected result is concatenation, e.g. `posts.Select…).Concat(products.Select(…))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this is a concatenation of to lists.

You can select your data into a new object, from both lists with a "one-liner", using [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8).

I am using an anonymous here, but you could also use an explicitly typed class.

```
posts.Select(c => new { 
         PostId = c.PostID,
         ProductId = null,
         PostDescrition = c.PostDescription,
         ProductDescription = null}).
      Concat(products.Select(c => new {
         PostId = null,
         ProductId = c.ProductId,
         PostDescrition = null,
         ProductDescription = c.ProductDescription}));
```

Do note: `posts` and `products` are not allowed to be `null`. They may be empty, but null will give a null reference exception.

---

Another note: there are also other options to `join` them on a specific field, or create a `union` (which is a joined and distinct version of Concat). These are related, but not similar.

Answer (score 0):

you could do similar like this:

```
    var postTemp = (from p in posts
                        let PostId = p.PostID
                        let ProductId = ""
                        let PostDes = p.PostDescription
                        let ProductDes = ""
                        select new {PostId, ProductId, PostDes, ProductDes }
                        ).ToList();

        var productsTemp = (from p in products
                            let PostId = ""
                            let ProductId = p.BusinessId
                            let PostDes = ""
                            let ProductDes = p.ProductDescription
                            select new{ PostId, ProductId, PostDes,ProductDes }).ToList();

        var allResidents = postTemp.Union<object>(productsTemp).ToList();
```

output will be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YyfJ.png

Answer (score 0):

If you need to combine lists with different types, you'll need to cast both lists to `object`, then you can can `concat` them.

So, for your `total` variable, you'll need to do this line instead :

```
var total = posts.ToList<object>().Concat(products.ToList<object>()).ToList();
```

then you can iterate the total list, but you'll also need to recast them to their original type to get their values (easier to handle).

here is a simple example :

```
    foreach (var item in total)
    {
        if(item.GetType() == typeof(GeneralPost))
        {
            var record = (item as GeneralPost);
            Console.WriteLine($"{record.PostID}\tnull\t{record.PostDescription}\tnull");
        }
        else
        {
            var record = (item as EnquiryProduct);
            Console.WriteLine($"null\t{record.BusinessId}\tnull\t{record.ProductDescription}");


        }

    }
```

the output of the above example will be :

```
1       null    Post 1  null
2       null    Post 2  null
3       null    Post 3  null
4       null    Post 4  null
null    1       null    ProductDesc 1
null    2       null    ProductDesc 2
null    3       null    ProductDesc 3
```